# Date validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a date string in this format - "DD-MM-YYYY"
this validates that successfully:

```
var dateFormat = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-\d{4}/ ;
if(!startDate.match(dateFormat)){
    alert("'Start Date' must be in format: DD-MM-YYYY");
    return false;
```

I need to check that the inserted date is after today's date(or today's date).
how can i do that with JavaScript?

I've tried this:
http://www.redips.net/javascript/date-validation/
with the separator, didn't work. suggestions?

Comment: Your code validates the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, but doesn't really validate the date, as it does not check the day against the length of the month.

Comment: You might consider looking at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) when working with dates in JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this is your current date in javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth()+1; // Zero indexed
```

All you need to do, from here, is to compare this with your start date!

Best regards!

[check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) maybe it helps to understand the date object.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [date.js](http://datejs.com), specifically...

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compare

> Compares the first date to the second date and returns an number
>   indication of their relative values. -1 = this is < date. 0 =
>   values are equal. 1 = this is > date.

The [`isAfter()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#isAfter) and the [`isBefore()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#isBefore) methods might be useful for your problem :)

Download the library here:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/detail?name=date.js&can=2&q=

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) pretty easily.

```
var input = moment(startDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
if (input < moment()) {
    // before today
} else {
    // after today
}
```

We're also adding date validation pretty soon. See more info about validation here: https://github.com/timrwood/moment/pull/306

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Could use some cleanup, but hopefully gets the point across.

```
var dateFormat = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(\d{4})/;
var dateMatch = startDate.exec(dateFormat);
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0); today.setMinutes(0); today.setSeconds(0); today.setMilliseconds(0);

if ((new Date(dateMatch[3], dateMatch[2] - 1, dateMatch[1])).getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
    // Date is after or on today
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check each date `getTime()` method and compare it. It's plain and simple, you don't need additional frameworks.

Here is an example that parses the dates from the strings, and then compares them:

```
var todayDate = "10-05-2012";​ // A sample date
var compareDate1 = "10-05-2012";
var compareDate2 = "03-05-2012";
var compareDate3 = "10-07-2012";

compareDates(todayDate, compareDate1);
compareDates(todayDate, compareDate2);
compareDates(todayDate, compareDate3);

function compareDates(date1String, date2String) {
    var date1 = parseDate(date1String);
    var date2 = parseDate(date2String);
    if(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
      alert("First date(" + date1String + ") is older than second date(" + date2String + ").");                
    } else if(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
      alert("First date(" + date1String + ") is younger than second date(" + date2String + ").");                
    } else {
      alert("The dates are the same day");   
    }
}

function parseDate(stringDateParam) {
    var parsedDay = parseInt(stringDateParam.substring(0,2));
    var parsedMonth = parseInt(stringDateParam.substring(3,5))-1;
    var parsedYear = parseInt(stringDateParam.substring(6,10));
    var parsedDate = new Date(parsedYear, parsedMonth, parsedDay, 0 , 0, 0, 0);
    return parsedDate;
}
​

// Output:
//
// First check: The dates are the same day
// Second check: First date(10-05-2012) is older than second date(03-05-2012).
// Third check: First date(10-05-2012) is younger than second date(10-07-2012).
```

You probably already have a function that parses string to date object, and you should implement a check similar to the one in function `compareDates` based on `getTime()` function.

If you have further questions, leave a comment. Good Luck!

JSFiddle working example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/2WBbA/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!
this did the trick:

```
var today = new Date();
var Tday = today.getDate();
var Tmonth = today.getMonth()+1; // Zero indexed
var Tyear = today.getFullYear();

var aoDate;
var separator= '-';
aoDate = startDate.split(separator);

var month = aoDate[1] - 0;
    var day = aoDate[0] - 0;
    var year = aoDate[2] - 0;

    if(year < Tyear){
        alert("'Start Date' must be today or after today!");
    return false;
    }
    if((year == Tyear) && (month < Tmonth)){
        alert("'Start Date' must be today or after today!");
    return false;
    }
    if((year == Tyear) && (month == Tmonth) && (day < Tday)){
        alert("'Start Date' must be today or after today!");
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most I was surprised a what js accepts as the constituent parts of a date. There may be holes in the code below which I would be glad to hear about but this seems to work for me. This assumes a DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm input format.

```js
function strToDate(dtStr) {
                   if (!dtStr) return null
                   let dateParts = dtStr.split("/");
                   let timeParts = dateParts[2].split(" ")[1].split(":");
                   dateParts[2] = dateParts[2].split(" ")[0];
                   // month is 0-based, that's why we need dataParts[1] - 1
                   return dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);
               }
               
// start of validation
var end_time = $('#tbDepartDtTm').val();
end_actual_time = strToDate(end_time);

// convert the date object back to a string in the required format
var dtString = ("0" + end_actual_time.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (end_actual_time.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + end_actual_time.getFullYear() + " " + ("0" + end_actual_time.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + end_actual_time.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

 if (dtString != end_time) {
      // if the string isn't the same as entered, it must be invalid. msg is a span element.
      msg.textContent = "Depart date is not a valid date.";
      return "Error";
  }
```