# Cut down the number of validations performed on a particular HTML form element.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, router

I am building one React app. Basically what this app does is, it has an HTML form to take the user data, store it and display a table on the basis of user data. Quite simple right ?? I am using react router to land the user on one of the pages either FORM, TABLE or EDIT. The FORM Page has a DATE element, validation restricts it to accept a date before today { multiple restriction are there e.g. Date format}. Now the problem is in EDIT mode the user is free to set any date, but as the same form is reflected in both FORM and EDIT mode, same validation are performed on both. Now i want to cut down the only date validation which restricts the it to be older than today in EDIT mode {rest validation e.g. Date Format and all must stay}.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you should add some code examples to show what you have done already.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523977/date-validation-with-javascript